# CSV loader includes space character on final column

Tags: gatling

I have data in a CSV and am loading it into my scenario. However, the values in the final column are parsed with a trailing space. (Actually, hexdump shows it to be the bytes `e2 80 0a` (unix mode) or `e2 80 a8` (dos mode).

The CSV (simplified)

```
speed,course
19.92,248.203125
```

The Simulation

```
  val conf = http
    .baseURL("http://myapp")
    .acceptHeader("image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .connectionHeader("keep-alive")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36")

  val requestsDS = csv("src/test/resources/mixed-route-load.csv").circular

  val scn = scenario("mixed route load")
    .feed(requestsDS)
    .exec {
      http("Load route")
        .get(s"/endpoint?course=${course}&speed=${speed}")
    }

  setUp(scn.inject(
    atOnceUsers(5),
    rampUsers(20).over(Duration(30, "s"))
  ).protocols(conf))
```

The result:

```
=========================
HTTP request:
GET http://myapp/endpoint?course=173.125183%E2%80%A8
headers=
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Host: myapp
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
400 Bad Request
headers=
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2016 04:55:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 95
Connection: keep-alive

body=
The query parameter 'course' was malformed:
'173.125183         ' is not a valid floating point value
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was encoded in the input file itself. Presumably an artifact of exporting from the OSX spreadsheet application Numbers. Gatling was converting it accurately.